# How to create paraview slice

Tags: paraview

I want to make Paraview slice in normal z direction (0,0,1) in python shell.

```
paraview.simple.Slice(*input, **params)
```

what should be input in `paraview.simple.Slice` to get a slice at particular location

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example script:

```
from paraview import simple as pvs
dataProducer = pvs.Wavelet()

slicer = pvs.Slice(Input=dataProducer, SliceType="Plane")
slicer.SliceType.Origin = [0, 0, 0]
slicer.SliceType.Normal = [0, 0, 1]

# To render the result, do this:
Show(slicer)
Render()
```

You can also you **Tools | Start Trace** to generate Python trace for actions you perform in the UI.